# MySQL: Get total hours, then multiply with rate, then rounding in one SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

My data looks like this:

```
UserID  Hours   BillRate
1   1.50    2.25
1   2.50    3.25
1   3.50    3.25
2   5.50    4.25
2   6.50    5.25
2   7.50    5.25
```

Is there anyway that I can get total spend for each person in one SELECT statement?
This is what I have.  It returns what I want, but I have to do 2 SELECT statements.

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(OneSpend) AS TotalSpend
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, ROUND(SUM(Hours)*BillRate,2) AS OneSpend
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY UserID, BillRate
) a
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, ROUND(SUM(Hours*BillRate), 2) AS TotalSpend
FROM mytable
GROUP BY UserID
```

According to the distributive property of multiplication over addition, `SUM(Hours)*BillRate` is the same as `SUM(Hours * BillRate)` when all the `BillRate` values are the same, as they are when you group by `BillRate`.

Comment: Your select clause looks incomplete.

Comment: Barmar, thank you!  That works.  I used to do the same, but somehow it returned wrong result.  I tested your query with different data set and it works correctly.